# Which category of music theory would the topic of "which scales to play over which chords" fall into?

Tags: theory, chords, scales, terminology, harmony

For example, in blues it's common to play a minor pentatonic scale over a major chord, and in a lot of rock music it is common to play the corresponding major/minor pentatonic scale over a major/minor chord.

Would this fall into the boundaries of harmony?

Comment: “Inverse harmonisation”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would this fall into the boundaries of harmony?

The answer is simple and it's yes.

There are many kinds of harmony. The blues harmony is different than the jazz which is different than the classical etc.